# Using numpy `as_strided` function to create patches, tiles, rolling or sliding windows of arbitrary dimension

Tags: arrays, numpy, convolution

Spent a while this morning looking for a generalized question to point duplicates to for questions about [`as_strided`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542135/sliding-window-using-as-strided-function-in-numpy) and/or [how to make generalized window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950124/creating-image-tiles-mn-of-original-image-using-python-and-numpy).  There seem to be a lot of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685772/will-results-of-numpy-as-strided-depend-on-input-dtype/45812234#45812234) on how to (safely) create patches, sliding windows, rolling windows, tiles, or views onto an array for machine learning, convolution, image processing and/or numerical integration.

I'm looking for a generalized function that can accept a `window`, `step` and `axis` parameter and return an `as_strided` view for over arbitrary dimensions.  I will give my answer below, but I'm interested if anyone can make a more efficient method, as I'm not sure using `np.squeeze()` is the best method, I'm not sure my `assert` statements make the function safe enough to write to the resulting view, and I'm not sure how to handle the edge case of `axis` not being in ascending order.

**DUE DILIGENCE**

The most generalized function I can find is [`sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L241) written by @eickenberg (as well as the apparently equivalent [`skimage.util.view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows)), but those are not well documented on the net, and can't do windows over fewer axes than there are in the original array (for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748469/transform-2d-array-to-a-3d-array-with-overlapping-strides/45748530#45748530) asks for a window of a certain size over just one axis).  Also often questions want a `numpy` only answer.

@Divakar created a generalized `numpy` function for 1-d inputs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084931/taking-subarrays-from-numpy-array-with-given-stride-stepsize), but higher-dimension inputs require a bit more care.  I've made a bare bones [2D window over 3d input method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540000/batch-convolution-2d-in-numpy-without-scipy/45541172#45541172), but it's not very extensible.

Comment: Feel free to edit that first paragraph if you can think of any other buzzwords people might search for.

Comment: In my experience, you should really use `skimage.util.view_as_windows()`. It is not worth it to roll your own.

Comment: @NilsWerner for 2D images?  Surely.  For higher-dimensional data where you want windows over arbitrary axes?  Not really. I do machine learning for mechanics and mechatronics, where my state spaces can have >10 dimensions and I may only want a window function over a small selection.

Comment: Why not? It works for any number of dimensions...

Comment: Ahh, it seems `skimage.util.view_as_windows()` has been updated to nD since I made this.  Well, in any case `numpy` is a much more common include than `skimage` for commercial APIs (was stuck dealing with the non-extensible `abaqus` API when I wrote this originally), so it should still be useful to somebody.

Comment: Yes, your solution is not useless (I have been [creating](https://gist.github.com/nils-werner/9d321441006b112a4b116a8387c2280c) and [proposing](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7753) my own solutions, too). But I have also learned that in most cases I can avoid all that pain and simply fall back to `skimage`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT JAN 2020**: Changed the iterable return from a list to a generator to save memory.

**EDIT OCT 2020**: Put the generator in a separate function, since mixing generators and `return` statements doesn't work intiutively.

Here's the recipe I have so far:

```
def window_nd(a, window, steps = None, axis = None, gen_data = False):
        """
        Create a windowed view over `n`-dimensional input that uses an 
        `m`-dimensional window, with `m <= n`
        
        Parameters
        -------------
        a : Array-like
            The array to create the view on
            
        window : tuple or int
            If int, the size of the window in `axis`, or in all dimensions if 
            `axis == None`
            
            If tuple, the shape of the desired window.  `window.size` must be:
                equal to `len(axis)` if `axis != None`, else 
                equal to `len(a.shape)`, or 
                1
                
        steps : tuple, int or None
            The offset between consecutive windows in desired dimension
            If None, offset is one in all dimensions
            If int, the offset for all windows over `axis`
            If tuple, the steps along each `axis`.  
                `len(steps)` must me equal to `len(axis)`
    
        axis : tuple, int or None
            The axes over which to apply the window
            If None, apply over all dimensions
            if tuple or int, the dimensions over which to apply the window

        gen_data : boolean
            returns data needed for a generator
    
        Returns
        -------
        
        a_view : ndarray
            A windowed view on the input array `a`, or `a, wshp`, where `whsp` is the window shape needed for creating the generator
            
        """
        ashp = np.array(a.shape)
        
        if axis != None:
            axs = np.array(axis, ndmin = 1)
            assert np.all(np.in1d(axs, np.arange(ashp.size))), "Axes out of range"
        else:
            axs = np.arange(ashp.size)
            
        window = np.array(window, ndmin = 1)
        assert (window.size == axs.size) | (window.size == 1), "Window dims and axes don't match"
        wshp = ashp.copy()
        wshp[axs] = window
        assert np.all(wshp <= ashp), "Window is bigger than input array in axes"
        
        stp = np.ones_like(ashp)
        if steps:
            steps = np.array(steps, ndmin = 1)
            assert np.all(steps > 0), "Only positive steps allowed"
            assert (steps.size == axs.size) | (steps.size == 1), "Steps and axes don't match"
            stp[axs] = steps
    
        astr = np.array(a.strides)
        
        shape = tuple((ashp - wshp) // stp + 1) + tuple(wshp)
        strides = tuple(astr * stp) + tuple(astr)
        
        as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
        a_view = np.squeeze(as_strided(a, 
                                     shape = shape, 
                                     strides = strides))
        if gen_data :
            return a_view, shape[:-wshp.size]
        else:
            return a_view

def window_gen(a, window, **kwargs):
    #Same docstring as above, returns a generator
    _ = kwargs.pop(gen_data, False)
    a_view, shp = window_nd(a, window, gen_data  = True, **kwargs)
    for idx in np.ndindex(shp):
        yield a_view[idx]
```

Some test cases:

```
a = np.arange(1000).reshape(10,10,10)

window_nd(a, 4).shape # sliding (4x4x4) window
Out: (7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4)

window_nd(a, 2, 2).shape # (2x2x2) blocks
Out: (5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2)

window_nd(a, 2, 1, 0).shape # sliding window of width 2 over axis 0
Out: (9, 2, 10, 10)

window_nd(a, 2, 2, (0,1)).shape # tiled (2x2) windows over first and second axes
Out: (5, 5, 2, 2, 10)

window_nd(a,(4,3,2)).shape  # arbitrary sliding window
Out: (7, 8, 9, 4, 3, 2)

window_nd(a,(4,3,2),(1,5,2),(0,2,1)).shape #arbitrary windows, steps and axis
Out: (7, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3) # note shape[-3:] != window as axes are out of order
```

Comment: Coincidentally been working on a very similar stuff (might be identical if I understand what it's supposed to accept for axis/window). Got a query - Can you show a sample run on shape for `m < n` case?

Comment: Added some test cases

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks. Earlier I tried : `window_nd(a, window=(3,2), axis=(0,1))` and was throwing error. And this is exact same task I have been working on too :)

Comment: I think the `generator` keyword is broken in Python 3.7.7 (and possibly earlier). It seems like as soon as there is a `yield` in the code, it will return the generator, even if the if-clause isn't triggered (i.e. `generator=False` also returns an iterator).

Comment: @skjerns, sorry that took me entirely too long to fix.