# Extract multiple windows/patches from an (image) array, as defined in another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image `im` which is an array as given by `imread`.  Say e.g.

```
im = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
               [2,3,4,5],
               [3,4,5,6],
               [4,5,6,7]]
```

I have another `(n,4)` array of `windows` where each row defines a patch of the image as `(x, y, w, h)`.  E.g.

```
windows = np.array([[0,0,2,2],
                    [1,1,2,2]]
```

I'd like to extract all of these patches from `im` as sub-arrays without looping through.  My current looping solution is something like:

```
for x, y, w, h in windows:
    patch = im[y:(y+h),x:(x+w)]
```

But I'd like a nice array-based operation to get all of them, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: How would you like to handle boundary cases?

Comment: But since the images can have different width and height, the shapes are not uniform of the images.

Comment: @Divakar in my case I won't have any windows which extend past the image by construction.  But let's say I'd like to just discard any windows that don't fit within the constraints of `im`, so they wouldn't show up in the resulting patches array.

Comment: do `w` and `h` ever change for a given `windows` array?

Comment: @DanielF yes, though if it simplifies I can deal with it elsewhere and have them be constant in this context.

Comment: You can't get a single array as a return then due to uneven dimensions.  Your output would be a list of window arrays at best, and then our loopy code is probably best (short of a `@jit` function maybe)

Comment: It's actually a very different problem depending on if the window changes. If it doesn't there's a bunch of solutions like `numpy`'s `as_strided`, `skimage`'s `view_as_windows`, or if you want something even more robust my own [`window_nd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w) function.

Comment: @J.Doe yes, sorry, I've marked one as accepted.  Both were fine.  I was waiting a bit to see if my comments might prompt some other solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For same window sizes, we could get views with help from [scikit-image's `view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows), like so -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

im4D = view_as_windows(im, (windows[0,2],windows[0,3]))
out = im4D[windows[:,0], windows[:,1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [191]: im4D = view_as_windows(im, (windows[0,2],windows[0,3]))

In [192]: im4D[windows[:,0], windows[:,1]]
Out[192]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 4],
        [4, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `scikit` is not available we can homebrew @Divakar's solution with `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`. The same constraint (all windows must have same shape) applies:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

im = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
               [2,3,4,5],
               [3,4,5,6],
               [4,5,6,7]])

windows = np.array([[0,0,2,2],
                    [1,1,2,2]])

Y, X = im.shape
y, x = windows[0, 2:]
cutmeup = as_strided(im, shape=(Y-y+1, X-x+1, y, x), strides=2*im.strides)
print(cutmeup[windows[:, 0], windows[:, 1]])
```

Output:

```
[[[1 2]
  [2 3]]

 [[3 4]
  [4 5]]]
```