# Take N first values from every row in NumPy matrix that fulfill condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, mask

I have a `numpy vector`, and a `numpy array`.

I need to take from every row in the matrix the first N (lets say 3) values that are smaller than (or equal to) the corresponding line in the vector.

so if this is my vector:

```
7,
9,
22,
38,
6,
15
```

and this is my matrix:

```
[[ 20.,   9.,   7.,   5.,   None,   None],
 [ 33.,  21.,  18.,   9.,   8.,   7.],
 [ 31.,  21.,  13.,  12.,   4.,   0.],
 [ 36.,  18.,  11.,   7.,   7.,   2.],
 [ 20.,  14.,  10.,   6.,   6.,   3.],
 [ 14.,  14.,  13.,  11.,   5.,   5.]]
```

the output should be:

```
[[7,5,None],
 [9,8,7],
 [21,13,12],
 [36,18,11],
 [6,6,3],
 14,14,13]]
```

Is there any efficient way to do that with masks or something, without an ugly `for` loop?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is it always sorted in descending order along rows?

Comment: Good point, In my case, yes. and also the `None`s will always come in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def takeN_le_per_row_broadcasting(a, b, N=3): # a, b : 1D, 2D arrays respectively
    # First col indices in each row of b with <= corresponding one in a
    idx = (b <= a[:,None]).argmax(1)

    # Get all N ranged column indices
    all_idx = idx[:,None] + np.arange(N)

    # Finally advanced-index with those indices into b for desired output
    return b[np.arange(len(all_idx))[:,None], all_idx]
```

**Approach #2**

Inspired by [`NumPy Fancy Indexing - Crop different ROIs from different channels`'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191338/), we can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) for efficient patch extraction, like so -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def takeN_le_per_row_strides(a, b, N=3): # a, b : 1D, 2D arrays respectively
    # First col indices in each row of b with <= corresponding one in a
    idx = (b <= a[:,None]).argmax(1)

    # Get 1D sliding windows for each element off data
    w = view_as_windows(b, (1,N))[:,:,0]

    # Use fancy/advanced indexing to select the required ones
    return w[np.arange(len(idx)), idx]
```