# how can I extract multiple random sub-sequences from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

say I have a sequence `s` and I'd like to select `n` random sub sequences from it each with length `l` and store in a matrix. Is there a more numpy way of doing that than

```
s = np.arange(0, 1000)
n = 5
l = 10
i = np.random.randint(0, len(s)-10, 5)
ss = np.array([s[x:x+l] for x in i])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for efficient patch extraction, like so -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

# Get sliding windows (these are simply views)
w = view_as_windows(s, l)

# Index with indices, i for desired output
out = w[i]
```

Related :

[NumPy Fancy Indexing - Crop different ROIs from different channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191060/numpy-fancy-indexing-crop-different-rois-from-different-channels)

[Take N first values from every row in NumPy matrix that fulfill condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380129/take-n-first-values-from-every-row-in-numpy-matrix-that-fulfill-condition)

[Selecting Random Windows from Multidimensional Numpy Array Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982894/selecting-random-windows-from-multidimensional-numpy-array-rows)

Comment: superb, solution.