# Multidimensional Slicing

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, performance, numpy, slice

I want to slice out parts of my array `foo` multiple times. Currently I am using a for loop which I want to substitute through matrix computation to get a better performance in terms of speed.

```
foo = np.arange(6000).reshape(6,10,10,10)
target = np.zeros((100,6,3,4,5))
startIndices = np.random.randint(5, size=(100))
```

This is my current approach.

```
for i in range(len(target)):
    startIdx=startIndices[i]
    target[i, :]=foo[:, startIdx:startIdx+3,
                        startIdx:startIdx+4,
                        startIdx:startIdx+5]
```

I tried to represent the slices as arrays, but I couldn't find the proper representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for efficient patch extraction, like so -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

# Get sliding windows (these are simply views)
WSZ = (1,3,4,5) # window sizes along the axes
w = view_as_windows(foo,WSZ)[...,0,:,:,:]

# Index with startIndices along the appropriate axes for desired output
out = w[:,startIndices, startIndices, startIndices].swapaxes(0,1)
```

Related :

[NumPy Fancy Indexing - Crop different ROIs from different channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191060/numpy-fancy-indexing-crop-different-rois-from-different-channels)

[Take N first values from every row in NumPy matrix that fulfill condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380129/take-n-first-values-from-every-row-in-numpy-matrix-that-fulfill-condition)

[Selecting Random Windows from Multidimensional Numpy Array Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982894/selecting-random-windows-from-multidimensional-numpy-array-rows)

[how can I extract multiple random sub-sequences from a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48920850/how-can-i-extract-multiple-random-sub-sequences-from-a-numpy-array)