# counting surrounding true's in numpy matrix (python)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make something similiar to minesweeper

input matrix:

```
matrix = [[true, false, false],
          [false, true, false],
          [false, false, false]]
```

if a bomb is on the field I do not count it as bomb is surrounding.

I thought about doing it with numpy convolve somehow but I am struggling with how to go through the matrix and always check the left, top, right and bottom fields of the actual field (in the case of a border I check "empty" fields which is 0 for sure)

[image]

Comment: 2d convolution with a donut-shaped seed.

Comment: no it doesn't have to be numpy, but I thought that this would be the best solution, just not sure how to get it to work.

@DanielF hmm how that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `scipy.signal.convolve2d`  :

```
import scipy
import numpy as np

# Input matrix, can be left as boolean
matrix = np.array([[True, False, False],
                   [False, True, False],
                   [False, False, False]])

# Our dougnut filter
W = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])

# Single convolve
res = convolve2d(matrix, W, 'same')
```

We get the exact result:

```
res
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Dang, got FGITW'd.  You can do all the padding and slicing using the `boundary` and `mode` parameters of `convolve2d` though.

Comment: mode=same is enough, doesnt need the boundary tho :P - boundary wrap makes the output actually wrong as it makes 1,2,1 to 2,1,2

Comment: Updated! no more boundary

Answer (score 1):

using only `numpy`, including `nd_window` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w/45960193#45960193)

```
m_pad = np.pad(matrix, ((1,1),(1,1)), 'constant', constant_values=(False, False))
filter = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]], dtype = bool)
adj_matrix = np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij', nd_window(m_pad, 3), filter)
```

Also, you can use [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html)

```
adj_matrix = convolve2d(matrix, filter, 'same', fillvalue = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple : using `numpy` you can simply use the `sum()` method (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.sum.html).

`np.matrix(matrix).sum()` will count all the `True` in your matrix.

So `np.matrix(matrix).sum() - matrix[1][1]` should return the number of mine around a cell.

And for me the easiest way to remove the border problem is to complete your matrix with `False` cells all around it.