# How to slice arrays with a percantage of overlapping

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of data like this:

```
numpy.array([[3, 7],[5, 8],[6, 19],[8, 59],[10, 42],[12, 54], [13, 32], [14, 19], [99, 19]])
```

which I want to split into number of chunkcs with a percantage of overlapping, for each column separatly... for example for column 1, splitting into 3 chunkcs with %50 overlapping (results in a 2-d array):

```
[[3, 5, 6, 8,],
        [6, 8, 10, 12,],
              [10, 12, 13, 14,]]
```

(ignoring last row which will result in [13, 14, 99] not identical in size as the rest).
I'm trying to make a function that takes the array, number of chunkcs and overlpapping percantage and returns the results.

Answer (score 1):

That's a window function, so use [`skimage.util.view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows):

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

out = view_as_windows(in_arr[:, 0], window_shape = 4, step = 2)
```

If you need `numpy` only, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w/45960193#45960193) recipe

Answer (score 0):

For numpy only, quite fast approach is:

```
def rolling(a, window, step):
    shape = ((a.size - window)//step + 1, window)
    strides = (step*a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

And you can call it like so:

```
rolling(arr[:,0].copy(), 4, 2)
```

Remark: I've got unexpected outputs for `rolling(arr[:,0], 4, 2)` so just took a copy instead.