# Get all possible chunks of length N

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with shape `(100000,)` over which I want to apply a sliding window of length 200 with a step size of 1. This means that the output array will have the shape `(99800,200)` - i.e., all unique chunks of length 200. I cannot find an efficient function in numpy that achieves this. I have tried:

```py
for i in range(data.shape[0] - 200):
    windows = np.append(windows , data[i:i+200]);
```

Which not only produces the wrong shape (1D), but it is also incredibly slow. Is there a fast function in Numpy to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using numpy \`as\_strided\` function to create patches, tiles, rolling or sliding windows of arbitrary dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w)

Comment: if you're not `numpy`-only, then `skimage.util.view_as_windows()` user-friendly as well.

Comment: Importantly, `as_strided` or `view` -based window functions don't take up any more disk space than the original array, while any method that copies the data (as in your code and @AlexP's answer) can easily cause `MemoryError`s.  The trade off is that you shouldn't read *back* into the windows in any vectorized way as this can cause a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try `stride_tricks` in `numpy`. It basically does not use up any extra space than the original array `a`, but creates a (virtual) strided array containing all the sliding windows.

```py
def slide(a, size):
    stride = a.strides[0]
    n = a.size - size + 1
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape = (n, size), strides = (stride, stride))

a = np.arange(100000)
slide(a, size = 200)
>>>array([[    0,     1,     2, ...,   197,   198,   199],
       [    1,     2,     3, ...,   198,   199,   200],
       [    2,     3,     4, ...,   199,   200,   201],
       ...,
       [99798, 99799, 99800, ..., 99995, 99996, 99997],
       [99799, 99800, 99801, ..., 99996, 99997, 99998],
       [99800, 99801, 99802, ..., 99997, 99998, 99999]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a numpy answer

```py
window_size = 10
i = np.arange(data.size - window_size + 1)
indices = np.add(np.array([np.arange(window_size)] * (data.size - window_size + 1)), i.reshape(-1, 1))

windows = data[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

Best function I've seen for this (non-`numpy`) is `skimage.util.view_as_windows()`

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

windows = view_as_windows(data, 200)
```

If you want `numpy`-only, the recipe in the dupe target is the most general answer, although @swag2198 suggests a more lightweight version in another answer here.