# Finding location of subarray in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find the location of a subarray in an numpy array.
For example, if the large array is of shape `(10000, 10, 10, 10)`, namely 10000 arrays of shape (10,10,10) and I want to find the location of the subarray of shape `(3,3,3)` as follows:

```
subarray = array(  
        [[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

So I will know that at the location of `n, i, j, k` I will get:
`largearray[n, i:i+subarray.shape[0], j:j+subarray.shape[1], k:k+subarray.shape[2]] == subarray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long ago I made a [`numpy`-only function for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w/45960193#45960193), but `skimage.util.view_as_windows` is a bit easier to implement.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import view_as_windows as winview

test = np.random.choice((0, 1), p = (.75, .25), size = (5,10,10,10))  #smaller test array
subarray = np.zeros((3,3,3))                                          #what we're looking for
view = winview(test, (1,3,3,3))                                       #a view over 3x3x3 windows 
out = np.all((view == subarray[None, ...]), (-4, -3, -2, -1))         #out=1 where the windows match
print(np.nonzero(out))                                                #output coordinates

Out[]: array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([2, 7], dtype=int64), array([4, 4], dtype=int64), array([1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

That gives coordinates for 2 locations with the 3x3x3 zeros box in my random input.

Why do this as windows?  Because looping takes forever in python and making the windows as a copy will kill your RAM.  `view` is just another way to address memory in `test` that is more useful for this type of comparison.